# AngularJS access controller functionalities in entire html page

Tags: javascript, angularjs, onsen-ui

I am using AngularJS in order to let users add products to their order. 
This works great: a user clicks on the + and the order gets added to an array. Now when the user clicks on 'personalize' he gets an overview of his order. But I can't seem to access my AngularJS controller or functionalities and data in this part of my html page..?

```
    <ons-page>
    <ons-toolbar>
        <div class="left"><a href="../index1.html"><img src="../images/backarrow.png"/></a></div>
        <div class="right"><p ng-controller="RootCtrl" id="uname" style="display:none;">{{custID}}</p></div>
    </ons-toolbar>    
    <div ng-controller="catFilter">
    <ons-tabbar ng-init="filterProductsByCats('Frappes')" position="top" var="tabbar" modifier="top-border">
      <ons-tab active='true' class="center" page="lattes.html" ng-repeat="cat in categories" ng-click="filterProductsByCats(cat.categoryName)" value="{{cat.categoryName}}">{{cat.categoryName}}</ons-tab> 
    </ons-tabbar>

    <!-- CATEGORY 1 -->    
    <ons-template type="text/ons-template" id="lattes.html">
      <ons-carousel swipeable overscrollable auto-scroll style="height: 100%; width: 100%;">
        <ons-carousel-item>  
          <ons-list>  
            <ons-list-item style="height:60px" ng-repeat="product in products | filter:search | orderBy: 'category'">
                <ul>
                 <li><a href="#" id="aantal" ng-click="productAdd($event,product.name, product.id, product.price)">+</a>
                 </li>
                 <li>
                    <ons-col width="100%">
                        <div class="name">
                          {{product.name}}
                        </div>
                    <div class="desc">
                        {{product.description}}
                    </div>
                    </ons-col>
                 </li>
                 <li><a href="#" id="aantal" ng-click="productRemove($event, product.id)">-</a></li>                    
                </ul>
            </ons-list-item>
          </ons-list>
      </ons-carousel-item>
        </ons-carousel>
    </ons-template>
```

**BOTTOM OVERVIEW**

```
    <ons-bottom-toolbar onclick="">
     <div>
         <div><a href=""; ng-click="globalNavi.pushPage('modal.html', {animation: 'lift'})"><img src="../images/uparrow.png"/></a></div>
        <p>{{getQuantity()}}</p>
        <p> PERSONALIZE </p>
        <p>{{getPrice()}}</p>
    </div>  
    </ons-bottom-toolbar>
  </ons-template>
```

**MODAL CHECKOUT**

```
   <ons-template id="modal.html">
    <ons-page>
    <ons-toolbar>
        <div class="left"><a href=""; ng-click="globalNavi.popPage()"><img src="../images/backarrow.png"/></a></div>
        <div class="right"><a><i class="fa fa-send fa-fw"></i></a></div>
    </ons-toolbar> 
    <div>
        <div class="left"><p>3 items</p></div>
        <div class="right"><p>{{getPrice()}}</p></div>
    </div>

    <ons-list width="100%">
      <ons-list-item class="list-item" ng-repeat="product in products">
        <ons-carousel swipeable initial-index="1" auto-scroll>
          <ons-carousel-item class="list-action-menu">
              <p><i class="fa fa-arrow-left fa-fw"></i>undo</p>
              <p><i class="fa fa-times fa-fw"></i></p>
          </ons-carousel-item>
          <ons-carousel-item class="list-action-item">
            <ons-row style="height:50px">
              <ons-col width="13%">
                <p>1</p>
              </ons-col>
              <ons-col width="72%">
                <div class="name">
                    {{product.name}}
                </div>
                <div class="desc">
                  ! extra milk
                </div>
              </ons-col>
            <ons-col width="15%">
                <p>M</p>
            </ons-col>    
            </ons-row>
          </ons-carousel-item>
        </ons-carousel>
      </ons-list-item>
    </ons-list>
    </ons-page>
   </ons-template>   
<!-- MODAL CHECKOUT         -->
</div>      
</ons-page>
```

**ANGULAR**

```
Onsen.controller("catFilter", ["$scope", "$http", "store", function($scope, $http, store){
    $scope.order = [];
    $scope.search = "";
    $scope.products = [];
    $scope.categories = [];   
    store.getCategories().then(function(data){
        $scope.categories = data;
    })
    store.getProducts().then(function(data){
        $scope.products = data;
    })    

    $scope.filterProductsByCats = function(category){
    $scope.search = category;
    };  
    $scope.getQuantity = function(){
        $scope.quan = 0;
            for(var b = 0; b<$scope.order.length;b++)
            {
                $scope.quan += $scope.order[b].aantal;
            }


        return $scope.quan + ' items';

    }
    $scope.getOrder = function(){
        return $scope.order;
    }
    $scope.getPrice = function(){
        $scope.price = 0;
            for(var b = 0; b<$scope.order.length;b++)
            {
                $scope.price += $scope.order[b].aantal * $scope.order[b].price;
            }

        $scope.price = $scope.price.toFixed(2);      
        return '€ ' + $scope.price;

    } 
    $scope.productRemove = function($event, pid){
        $scope.productid = pid;
        if($scope.order.length > 0)
        {
            for(var b = 0; b<$scope.order.length;b++){
               if($scope.order[b].prodid == pid)
               {
                   if($scope.order[b].aantal > 1)
                   {
                      $scope.order[b].aantal--;
                      document.getElementById('aantal').innerHTML = document.getElementById('aantal').innerHTML - 1;
                   }
                   else
                   {
                       $scope.order.splice(b);
                       document.getElementById('aantal').innerHTML = '+';
                       //update quantity in app UI!
                   }
               }
            }
        }
    }
    $scope.productAdd = function($event,pname, pid, pprice) {
        $scope.pzelfdeid = -1;
        $scope.pzelfde = -1;
        $scope.prodname = pname;
        $scope.prodid = pid;
        $scope.price = pprice;
        if($scope.order.length == 0){
            $scope.order.push({prodid: $scope.prodid, prodname: $scope.prodname, aantal: 1, price: $scope.price});
            $event.currentTarget.innerHTML = 1;
        }        
        else if($scope.order.length > 0){
            for(var b = 0; b<$scope.order.length;b++)
            {
                if($scope.order[b].prodid == pid)
                {
                    /*alert('hetzelfde');                
                    $scope.order[b].aantal++;
                    $event.currentTarget.innerHTML = $scope.order[b].aantal;*/
                    $scope.pzelfdeid = $scope.order[b].prodid;   
                    $scope.pzelfde = b;
                }
            }
            if($scope.pzelfde > -1)
            {
                $scope.order[$scope.pzelfde].aantal++;
                $event.currentTarget.innerHTML = $scope.order[$scope.pzelfde].aantal;             
            }
            else
            {
                $scope.order.push({prodid: $scope.prodid, prodname: $scope.prodname, aantal: 1, price: $scope.price});
                $event.currentTarget.innerHTML = 1;               
            }
        }

    }
    $scope.showorder = function(){
        console.log($scope.order);    
    }

}])

Onsen.factory('store', function($http, $q){
    function _getCategory (){
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        $http.get('/localsites/api/categories').success(function (data) {
                deferred.resolve(data);
            })
        return deferred.promise;
    }

    function _getProducts (){
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        var prods = [];
        $http.get('/localsites/api/products').success(function (data) {
            for(var i = 0;i<data.length;i++)
            {
                prods[i] = {id: data[i][0], name: data[i][1], price: data[i][2], category: data[i][3], description: data[i][4]};            
            }
            deferred.resolve(prods);
        })
        return deferred.promise;
    }
        return {
         getCategories: _getCategory,
         getProducts : _getProducts
        };

});
```

I am able to access the controller and all of its data an functionalities in the page and the bottom overview BUT in the modal checkout I can't seem to get these data to show.. Like for example {{product.name}}?

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: hey please provide some link like fiddle , plunkr etc.

Comment: I don't know much about this angular module you are using. But it seems that your modal may have its own scope. So you can't access your controller scope from the modal (but you can access the modal's one).